# ResourceBundle can't find resources in target/test-classes

Tags: java, junit, resourcebundle

My problem is that when resource bundle tries to get resources during JUnit test I get MissingResourceException, but all files that located in src/test/resources are compiled into target/test-classes and I even can reach them using

```
 ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("someFile.properties").getFile());
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

'classLoader.getResource()' may be causing the issue. Try getting it through ResourceAsStream which returns InputStream. for example:-

InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("filename");

Answer (score 0):

I checked File's code. I found there is no such constructor that construct a File object with a file object.

If you do maven test does copy resource file to test-classes.

try this

```
// this will show your resoure root.
File file = new File(getClass().getResource("/").getPath());


// debug you may find your file here.
File[] resoureces = file.listFiles();
```

or just use

```
File file = new File(getClass().getResource("/").getPath() + "someFile.properties");
```